# Youtube video url regex

Tags: regex, video, youtube

I want to create a regex where url given will output me video id. I know that youtube id always has 11 characters, my regex kind of works, but it doesn't work when someone shared a video which is already played: i.e when you open a video it starts at x of seconds.

Please view my example here:

https://regex101.com/r/kgVkTE/1

```
([0-9A-Z{11}])\w+
```

Example url:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MI9tFPT6yK4&t=17s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48Y_jWQDDiw
https://www.youtube.com/MI9tPtdas5
https://www.youtube.com/9MI9tPtdas5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your input strings, you could use:

```
(?<=v=|/)\w{10,11}
```

See your [**modified demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kgVkTE/4).
This requires either `v=` or a `/` right before ten or eleven word characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming based on your description that the ID will always have 11 characters. If that is always the case then you can simply use:

```
\w{11}
```

- `\w` represents alphabets, numbers and underscore
- `{11}` makes sure 11 such characters appear

However, your examples has one with 10 characters, for that:

```
\w{10,11}
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgVkTE/3)